# Get boolean from a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, boolean, jtextfield

I am trying to take the values from the text fields below to use with `parent.addNewRoom(roomNo,roomEnSuite);` but roomEnSuite is a Boolean value in the parent class. What is the correct procedure to get a Boolean from a JTextField?

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae)     
    {
        String item = ae.getActionCommand(); 

        if ( item.equals("Confirm"))         
        {
            String roomNo = nameJTextField.getText();
            String roomEnSuiteS = idJTextField.getText();
            parent.addNewRoom(roomNo,roomEnSuite);
            this.dispose();
        }
        else if ( item.equals("Cancel"))        
        {
        parent.resetButtons();
        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the user meant to be typing in 'True' or 'False' into the JTextField?

Comment: Yes the user types true or false into the JTextField

Comment: LOL. You could also use 26 checkboxes, each with a different letter, to help the user typing words :-)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to validate the input? Like, if it is the one you like = true else it is = false.

Comment: Using a JTextField for a boolean isn't a good way to go, as there's many variations as to what the user could type. It would be better to use a checkbox or radio button component.

Comment: I am adding the rooms to a hostel, so it merely states whether the room is ensuite or not.

Comment: A checkbox is the appropriate component to let a user enter a boolean value. Use a checkbox. Have you ever typed "true" in any serious application?

Comment: That I understand, but I should iterate that using a JCheckbox/JRadioButton would be easier to handle. As for what you want, a simple string comparison as to whether the value is 'true' or 'false' should work. Set a local boolean to true or false depending on what the user types.

Comment: Apologies @Neeta i was a couple of comments behind. I am now looking into checkboxes.

Comment: This should help if you're having any trouble: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html.. which I now see that Robin has posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a full answer from my above comments:

Handling `boolean` input using a `JTextField` would not be a good way to go about things as there are many variations the user could type `yes`/`no`/`true`/`false`, etc. mispelling?

Using a `JRadioButton` (for single answers) or `JCheckbox` (for multiple answers) would be a better way to go about handling `true` or `false` input. I would suggest a `JRadioButton` as you wouldn't want the user checking `true` and `false`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the user entered the string `true` or `false`, you can turn it into a `boolean` with:

```
boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(idJTextField.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

A `JTextField` is meant to provide `String`s. So unless you want the user to type `true` or `false` in the textfield (or whatever string you will parse to a boolean), there are better options available

- a [`JCheckBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html), which is typically used for toggle settings, like true-false
- [`JRadioButton`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) (one for each setting, so two in this case)

And here a [link to the corresponding Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) with examples on how to use these buttons

But if you really want to got with a textfield, then you should [get the text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) from it and parse it by using for example [`Boolean.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value entered is always going to be true or false you can get a Boolean using;

`boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(enSuiteJTextField.getText());`